# At least one checkbox selected - Asp.Net MVC - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I want to validate a form at client side by using the "@Html.ValidationMessageFor".
It's working correctly for textbox.
I also have some group of checkboxes in the form.
I would like to use the same way to validate that at least one check box by group is selected.
But if I'm not mistaking, the jquery validation plugin uses the name of the checkboxes to know if at least one is selected (example: http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form1").validate({
                    rules:{
                        spamName: {
                            required: true,
                        },
                    },
                    messages:{
                        spamName:{
                        required: "This is my custom message",
                        },
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .block {
                display: block;
            }
            form.cmxform label.error {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="cmxform" id="form1" method="get" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Spam</legend>
                <label for="spam_email">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_email" value="email" name="spamName" required>Spam via E-Mail
    </label>
                <label for="spam_phone">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_phone" value="phone" name="spamName">Spam via Phone
    </label>
                <label for="spam_mail">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="spam_mail" value="mail" name="spamName">Spam via Mail
    </label>
                <label for="spamName" class="error">This field is required custom message.</label>
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And so the checkboxes should have the same name by group.

It means that it's will not be possible to retrieve which values are selected after submitting the form as the name is used to bind the html form to the model by adding the index property in the name (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Does someone know or has a solution to bypass this issue?

The code sample is:

```
public class Mandatory
{
    public Mandatory()
    {
        CheckboxItems = new List<CheckboxItem>();
    }

    public IList<CheckboxItem> CheckboxItems { get; set; }
}
public class CheckboxItem
{
    public bool CheckboxValue { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

In the view:

```
@model WebApplication20.Models.Mandatory
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckboxItems)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CheckboxItems)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
}
```

The Editor Template used:

```
@model WebApplication20.Models.CheckboxItem
<div class="form_row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name, Model.Name)
    <label for="@Model.CheckboxValue"></label>
    <span class="content-checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.CheckboxValue)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CheckboxValue, Model.Name)
    </span>
</div>
```

And finally in the homecontroller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var items = new Mandatory();
    items.CheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem
    {
        CheckboxValue = true, 
        Name = "test 1",
    });

    items.CheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem
    {
        CheckboxValue = false,
        Name = "test 2",
    });

    items.CheckboxItems.Add(new CheckboxItem
    {
        CheckboxValue = true,
        Name = "test 3",
    });

    return View(items);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Mandatory test)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thx!

Comment: Seems, top HTML snippet is a test case with plain html, not within `asp.net mvc`. Would like to know whether you're using `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation`?

Comment: Nothing out of the box will solve this. Creating server side validation is easier enough but client side validation would require creating your own validator which would only work for one specific property within your model. It would be far easier to just handle the `submit` event, and cancel the event and display a message if none are checked (and handle the change event of all `checkboxes` to remove the message)

Comment: Venkaka, indeed I'm using the unobtrusive validation. the html snippet is there to show that jquery validation works only when the checkboxes have the same name. If it's possible to get the validation with different checkbox names, I can adapt the asp.net mvc to render the correct html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I implemented:

- Add an extra string property in the model (Mandatory class in my example), with the "required" attribute
- Display this property as hidden field
- Implement the onchange jquery event on all checkboxes. In this event, I check if at least one checkbox is checked.
- If at least one checkbox is checked, I fill the value of the new property displayed as hidden field. Otherwise, I remove the value of this hidden field.
- Then I call the "valid" method on my hidden field to automatically display or remove the error message.

As the field used for the validation is hidden (one by checkbox group), the default jquery validation behavior needs to be modified:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: ""
    });
```